# How to delete a line using sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a input file with following pattern-

```
    8799,,2015-06-29 04:00:00+0000,
    FIT-I6-INL-PCG,['3.MYFIT-LTR-DYN'],2015-03-11 04:00:00+0000,
```

Here I copied three different field separated by , (comma) I wanted to delete every line which has empty field. in above case 1st line has an empty field SO the o/p should be

```
   FIT-I6-INL-PCG,['3.MYFIT-LTR-DYN'],2015-03-11 04:00:00+0000,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -i.bak -E '/^,|,,/d' file

cat file
FIT-I6-INL-PCG,['3.MYFIT-LTR-DYN'],2015-03-11 04:00:00+0000,
```

`/^,|,,/d` will delete a line if comma is 1st char or if there are 2 commas together.

Comment: In my `sed` I don't even need the `-E` (and I wouldn't expect to need it in Sun `sed` (for instance) ; -) ). Good luck to all.

Comment: My OSX `sed` needed it actually. It didn't like `sed '/^,\|,,/d'`

Comment: gnu sed also supports `-E`

Comment: is that an undocumented feature? I don't see it in `man sed |grep -- '-E'`

Comment: Indeed, POSIX basic regular expressions do not recognize `\|`.  That is a GNU extension.  On the other hand, POSIX extended regular expressions do recognize `|`, but POSIX does not define any `sed` option to make it use EREs instead of BREs.

Answer (score 2):

With grep:

```
grep -v '^,\|,,' file
```

With sed:

```
sed '/^,\|,,/d' file
```

If you want to change the file in-place, then:

```
sed -i.bak '/^,\|,,/d' file
# Or with grep:
# echo "$(grep -v '^,\|,,' file)" >file
```